# Don't hide downvoted questions in tag filters

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, tag-filters

An undocumented (as far as I know) feature of [stackexchange.com tag filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters) is that it doesn't show closed questions. This makes some sense if you see them a a way to follow good questions across multiple sites, though it is somewhat confusing that the tag filters work differently than the newest questions tab on the sites themselves.

There's an additional feature that hides downvoted questions which I discovered when I wondered why I wasn't seeing certain questions in my tag filter. I thought initially it was triggered by the same threshold that hides questions on the frontpage (below -4 for most sites), but that isn't true. **All questions with a score of -1 and below** are hidden, which doesn't make any sense to me, so I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

In any case I think this should be changed, and downvoted questions should appear in tag filters.

Comment: `which doesn't make any sense to me` -- Why?  If you're referring to the FAQ tab, questions with a score of -1 are clearly not considered useful by the community. Try the `active` tab instead.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The tag filters are similar to the newest question list, and that one shows closed questions as well as downvoted ones. I could understand if severely downvoted questions are excluded, even if I don't agree with it, but a score of -1 doesn't mean anything. A single downvote is meaningless, it shouldn't hide the question from me.

Comment: I agree, we need 5 votes to close/delete, so we should need 5 downvotes to hide. And downvote a question doesn't cost any point, this confirm that it doesn't mean a lot.

Comment: Might be useful to have the ability to set a threshold for question score in a tag filter with the possibility of setting it to show all questions regardless of score.

Comment: A feature request related to the first line of your post: [(Add an option to) include closed questions in SE Filtered Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324083/335251)

Comment: Note – Apparently this issue might no longer exist? (I got [this MSE post that has a score of -6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343876/335251) to show up in the preview, at least, for a tag filter for [navigation] across all Meta sites. I didn't bother actually making the filter, due to issues with deleting tag filters...)