# (Add an option to) include closed questions in SE Filtered Questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

[Stack Exchange's Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) is a tool where users can see a list of 100 questions based on certain rules from multiple sites on the same page. However, *closed questions are currently excluded from the list* (e.g. compare [newest MSO questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest) with [newest MSO Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/362069/meta-stack-overflow?sort=newest)).

> **"Newest" questions** with a duplicate question
> [image: "Newest" questions with 1 question closed as duplicate]
>
> **"Newest" Filtered Questions**, missing the duplicate
> [image: "Newest" Filtered Questions with duplicate excluded]

While it might be convenient for users who are looking for interesting questions to be answered, a broader use case for me is to *monitor* all new questions so that I can still review already-closed questions.

I'm thinking of adding 2 checkboxes to (1) include closed, and/or (2) duplicate questions that will affect globally to the current filter as the starter, though finer customization on *each rule* is also welcomed (but not required for now).

However, did I miss something, like some possible flaws/dangerous misuse cases?