# Question shows up when I search for a tag, but not in a Filtered Questions

Tags: bug, tags, search, tag-filters

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184124/good-frontend-plugin-to-send-and-recieve-end) shows up if I search for the [`[clojure]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure) tag, but isn't included in the [Filtered Questions list for the same tag](https://stackexchange.com/filters/336233/all-clojure?sort=newest).

The only reason I can think of is the question starts with a Javascript tag, not a Clojure one. I would think it would include any questions that include the tag though.

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how Filtered Questions work? Is there a way to have them include questions that are tagged with Clojure, even if they're considered predominately a question for a different tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184124/good-frontend-plugin-to-send-and-recieve-end) you cite is currently on-hold. Questions that are [on-hold or closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) do not appear in the Filtered Questions list cf. this related [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324083/add-an-option-to-include-closed-questions-in-se-filtered-questions). This behavior is probably [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) but I guess only someone from the Stack Exchange team would be able to provide you a justification for this.