# SE sites should have an RSS feed that includes Meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, feed

There should be a combined Main + Meta RSS feed for every SE site. This would allow someone who is interested in both the topic and the community to subscribe to a single feed that contains all relevant content.

For people (like me) who use RSS feed to email services, this would also mean a single email rather than two when there is new content. For people who use feed readers, it would be one less feed to manage.

Of course, this shouldn't replace the other feeds. It should just be an option.

Comment: Meta and main are completely different categories, so I'm all for keeping the feeds separate.

Comment: Do you want just the questions from both main and meta (which is already possible), or all activities (which might not be possible for now)?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I'll edit to be more clear. Personally, I'm just interested in new questions. I'm not sure if "all activity" would be valuable to anyone, but it wouldn't be valuable to me. My workflow is to get a feed of questions as they are added to the site. If it's something that is interesting to me, I can now follow or bookmark it on-site to get more detailed information, but I don't need anything separate.

Comment: @amon I'm not proposing getting rid of the separate feeds. I know that I don't care about Meta on all sites. There should just be an option for a combined "all questions for this community" on both Main and Meta,

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange's [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) might be the workaround (or the solution) to this.

Example: [All questions (including meta) on SoftEng.SE](https://stackexchange.com/filters/396046/all-questions-including-meta-on-softeng-se)

The filter lists up to 100 [non-closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324083/add-an-option-to-include-closed-questions-in-se-filtered-questions) questions, either all of them or based on certain tags, even from multiple sites. It also allows for emailing new questions directly, though only the filter creator can fill it.

[image: example setting of the filter]

Last but not least, there's also [an RSS feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/396046/all-questions-including-meta-on-softeng-se?sort=newest) for anyone located at the bottom of the list that shows 30 questions from the filter.

[image: RSS feed for the filter]

Comment: Note that I haven't personally tested the email update nor the RSS feed because my filters are mostly noisy...

Comment: I will have to play around with this. Looking at this, I may have tried something like this before and ran into issues, but I could be thinking of something else. I'm also curious if this (and other things on stackexchange.com) are actually supported or if they are likely to break.

Comment: @ThomasOwens ah, [the filter could sporadically return empty list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308235/filters-sporadically-come-up-empty), but nowadays I've never encountered this issue anymore. Also, I use this feature almost daily, and I believe features on SE.com are actually supported but just rarely promoted...