# Could we go to the meta sites more quickly?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, per-site-meta, navigation

Currently when wanting to see the current questions in a meta site of a specific community (without using the URL because that would involve extra work), this means I have to:

- Click on the Stack Exchange button and the click on the meta site link (Total: 2 clicks); or
- Go to my user profile, from there click on Profiles dropdown, choose "meta user", and then can click on Home or Questions from left sidebar (Total: 4 clicks)

Not sure if I'm the only one, but when it comes to switching the site, I never/rarely use the Stack Exchange button. Even if I would, that would still take 2 clicks.

Could we have in nav-links one item with Meta/Non-meta? That would reduce Total clicks to 1 and give more incentive to go there.

Comment: Two clicks is already pretty fast, I don't think there's any need for it to be faster. If you're asking about discoverability that might be a different issue though.

Comment: You're right, it's a mixture of both. In one side we have the clicks (and asociated loading page), in the other it's not very intuitive to find (specially new users) and if we use url then it requires diferent input devices also.

Comment: My userscript, [SearchbarNavImprovements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) adds links to child meta sites from the main in the left sidebar, and vice-versa from meta sites, among other features including advanced and saved search, and  ability to search main, child metas, and MSE from the topbar.

Comment: Oh that's great @SamuelLiew, do you care to write that as an answer? Indeed solves the problem for now.

Comment: @V2Blast any extra details about the decision to defer this?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: Sorry, I meant to leave a comment about it here. We’ve reviewed this request and have moved it to our backlog. The company is currently doing research into navigation and UI improvements (see this post for more info: [Navigation and UI research starting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384406/335251)); these kinds of improvements would be made based on our findings there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The left side bar is very underutilised and could easily have a link to Meta. This could be gated behind rep if there's a concern that new users will go there before they can post, or it could be a user preference to turn it on/off.

Comment: This might be true for the most of us, but I wonder what the left sidebar would look like when you are a member of one, or multiple, teams.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm a member of multiple teams (4) and one more item in the menu wouldn't bother in Desktop.

Comment: How would this work on mobile (my main access point)?

Comment: @Matt Fair question. It probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out by [curiousdannii](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343885/364217),

> The left side bar is very underutilised and could easily have a link
> to Meta.

Samuel Liew, nonetheless, was a couple of steps ahead and [built a userscript named SearchbarNavImprovements](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/64722) that can do this

[image: SearchbarNavImprovements]

as he says in the comments of this question

> adds links to child meta sites from the main in the left sidebar, and
> vice-versa from meta sites, among other features including advanced
> and saved search, and ability to search main, child metas, and MSE
> from the topbar.

- [View the source code](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js)
- [Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/SearchbarNavImprovements.user.js) (Notice that Userscripts require Tampermonkey to be installed on your browser.)

**Ideally we wouldn't need such a script and it would be there by default.**

Answer (score 8):

While this is still being reviewed, I'd like to post two methods that actually require only *one* click or *no* clicks at all.

---

On every Stack Exchange site (except Stack Overflow), if you scroll down to the footer of the page, you'll see a link (under the "[Site Name]" heading) called "Feedback":

[image]

Clicking on "Feedback" will lead you directly to the [Site Name] meta.

There are, of course, two issues with this:

1. Discoverability: Not very intuitive to find. Having a link to "Meta" in the left sidebar (as suggested by other users) would be a better option.
2. Requires scrolling: You need to scroll to get to the footer of the page every time you want to visit the meta site. But it's faster on mobile (just one strong swipe and you've reached the bottom).

---

You can switch to the meta site (and vice versa) with *no* clicks at all, using keyboard shortcuts:

1. From your profile [settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), enable keyboard shortcuts.
2. From anywhere on the site, you can easily go to the meta site (and vice versa) using <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Here's a demonstration of this method on Super User:

[image]

Comment: Regarding requires scrolling: One can consider using the End button on keyboard :)

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion: when you already have a meta account, add another icon in the top bar:

> [image: top bar with meta link]

The icon is small and not intrusive, and there's still enough room left for the other contents of the top bar.

(The icon will be the site-meta logo)

Comment: The top bar is already too full. Maybe if they removed two of the three hamburger menus then there'd be space for a Meta icon.

Comment: @curiousdannii actually the reputation and badges are the "problem" I don't really remember how come it wasn't there two years ago. :/

Comment: What do you mean "have a meta account"? Isn't meta user page created automatically when one creates a "main" account?

Comment: @RandomPerson the per-site meta account is created on the fly, when the user first visit the meta site. You can see proof by going now to the profile of [this new user on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/296394/matsonwatson), note that user has no link to meta account, only to the Network profile. Moreover, trying to manually visit [their meta account](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/296394) (using the same user ID) leads for Page Not Found. If that user would visit the per-site meta, account will be auto created.

Comment: Worth to mention chat is even more weird: chat profile also created on the fly, but not only when the user visit chat for the first time, but also when *any user visits that user's chat profile*. We'll never see "Page Not Found" like with meta site (assuming user exists and not deleted), but rather the chat profile will get created on spot if doesn't exist already. :)