# Is the icon update for accessibility purposes?

Tags: support, design, icons, left-nav

I just noticed an update on the SE icons (on many sites if it's not all):

[image]

Is this for accessibility purposes? Or is it for purely aesthetic purposes?

---

<sup>I'm just curious about the reason for the change</sup>

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392163/design-vision-updates-to-the-left-navigation

Comment: The Teams advert is buggy in Orca, but the new sidebar does seem to work properly in it – and the icon / text combination is usually an accessibility winner. The only thing I can see that could make it better is explanatory tooltips (actual `title=` tooltips), but that'd probably only be useful on Saves and I can't think what to write there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have no direct insight into the minds of the designers, the change does provide an accessibility benefit for some users, namely non-native speakers. Look for example at the following and tell me if you'd be able to navigate as well without the icons:

[image: Japanese SO menu]

(There are a number of reasons why this situation would happen. The most straightforward example would be that almost every "X language" site allows users to post entirely in language X instead of English.)

In any case, there's no negative to having icons here.